# Why does popbackstack call onCreateView of the fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

Trying to figure why onCreateView is called when I popbackstack the fragment.

Using the following code:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("tag1", 1); 
ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); 
ft.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag1")); 
ft.commit();
```

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 79, size is 79
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at edu.pacific.pocketrx.FlashCardFrag.onCreateView(FlashCardFrag.java:72)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:764)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1562)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3.run(FragmentManager.java:495)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code to remove fragment:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("tag1", 1);
ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag1"));
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Perhaps with some code? onCreateView will of course be called on a previous fragment if the the backstack lands you there..

Comment: Could you paste your logcat in to the question instead please - it's easier to read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact fragment manager doesn't store your hidden fragment it stores only a state

class BackStackState implements Parcelable

see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState%28android.os.Handler%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29

and when you pop a fragment, fragment manager tries to recreate a previous view to display it.

see moveToState method

Comment: can you clarify it please?

Comment: @veon, Is there a way to just remove the fragment from the stack without having the previous one recreated? What if I want to remove several fragments at once, or just want to replace the stack with a new fragment?

Answer (score -1):

**Update**: Please ignore this answer it's clearly wrong and I had no idea what I was talking about (it was 3 years ago!)

Original (**incorrect**) answer:

In my case I had 2 fragments on the back stack, calling this:

```
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Seems to trigger `onCreateView()` even for the current fragment on top which is quite confusing. I've replaced it with popBackStackImmediate:

```
FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

And `onCreateView()` is now not called for the top fragment.

Comment: onCreateView() is still being called for me, even after started using popBackStackImmediate().