# popBackStack() behavior differs after support-library upgrade from 23.1.1 to 25.1.0

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, back-stack

After upgrade from Android support library `23.1.1` to the latest `25.1.0` the behavior from `popBackStack()` has changed in our application.

For example I have three `FragmentTransactions` on BackStack. Now the fourth FragmentTrsansaction is added to BackStack. FragmentTransactions are like this:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container_single, target, CoreActivity.FRAGMENT_TAG_LEFT)
    .addToBackStack(<CONCRETE_TRANSACTION_NAME>)
    .commit();
```

Fragment#4 has logic where it routes to Fragment#5 during `onViewCreated()` automatically (I know, it’s ugly and I have to change this). Anyway, when I want to leave Fragment#5 I want to resume to the Fragment that has been shown prior to Fragment#4. I do this by transaction name:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(“<CONCRETE_TRANSACTION_NAME_4>”, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

or this:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(“<CONCRETE_TRANSACTION_NAME_3>”, 0);
```

But with this call the `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()` of Fragment#4 will be called and Fragment#5 will be added immediately to the BackStack. Even if I resume to Fragment#1 `onViewCreated()` is called for every Fragment on the BackStack – for Fragment#2, Fragment#3 and Fragment#4, even if they don’t matter for the FragmentTransaction I want to return to.

Under support library `23.1.1` I successfully jump back to Fragment#3. Fragment#4 is popped inclusive without calling `onViewCreated()`. This seemed more intuitive and right to me, because calling `onViewCreated()` for Fragments "outside" of my FragmentTransaction seems unnecessary?

I know, `addToBackStack()` only saves the transactional states and not the Fragments itself and Fragments maybe have to be recreated.

There are similar [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21709107/2006827) to that, but I want to understand why it breaks after support library update. I can’t find the change anywhere. Was this a Bug or is it a Bug now?

I'am going on to change my code.

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**
I've got more lifecycle issues/changes after upgrading to support-library 25.1.0. There is an [Google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230415) where I commented my issues additionally. Currently I had to go back to the latest 24.2.1 and keep an eye on this topic. This is just my temporary solution. These issues start with support-library 25.0.0.

Comment: I have troubles with back button in this version. I wonder if it is related to this lifecycle issue as well. Activity instance is created again.

Comment: I checked this. When I go back my Activity is not recreated. It is paused and resumed like expected between Activities. But by back bahavior of fragments has changed in it's order. It seems it is not related to the new library version. Maybe your activity is recreated by Android due to low memory for example?

Comment: When I use support 25.x, I have crashes after using back button. When I return to 24.x, it works well. Several devices. When I have some time I have to distill out minimum viable test.

Answer (score 6):

Pay attention to the new support **25.1.0**.

Something changed in the **fragment lifecycle**.
Now there is **new functionality** to optimize the operations and postpone fragment transitions.

Read this:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230415

Comment: Yes thanks, I recognized that already. Even if I use   `transaction.setAllowOptimization(false);` nothing changes and `onCreateView()`is still called. But dou you think this is an effect of the new optimizations and we maybe can not switch to old behavior?

Comment: I think that the new lifecycle changes the transations and the behaviour also in your case.

Comment: I think too it could be the new optimization. Meanwhile I left a comment on the Google issue, maybe a developer can say something concrete about that. Locally I changed my code too, so that `onCreateView()` no longer calls again a FragmentTransaction. I think other peaople are figthing with this too and hope we get some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. Fixed in 25.3.0